# Make a div appear on hover over another div

Tags: css, html, hover

I am trying to have it so that a little colored box comes up when you hover over an image.I have recreated the scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/

The div shows up properly when I remove the `visibility:hidden` attribute, but not when I try to use the hover part. Any suggestions as to how to fix this? I have also tried `display:none` going to `display:inline` or `display:block`, but no luck

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/2/

Comment: why do you have #content:hover + #hoverbar? the + sign is for elements that are siblings, not nested elements which is what you have. remove the + sign.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace

```
#content:hover + #hoverbar{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

with

```
#content:hover > #hoverbar{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

or

```
#content:hover #hoverbar{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

The plus sign '+' is for siblings. In your case the div is nested.

[Here the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/8/)